# In which class in the source code of spring-boot or spring is the application.yml or application.properties file processed?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In which class in the source code of spring-boot or spring is the application.yml file or application.properties processed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For spring boot (version 2.x) the application properties are loaded from the environment into the context via a [PropertySourceLoader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/env/PropertySourceLoader.html).

In for example the `spring-boot-2.6.3.jar` we can find the following file:
`META-INF/spring.factories`

```
# PropertySource Loaders
org.springframework.boot.env.PropertySourceLoader=\
org.springframework.boot.env.PropertiesPropertySourceLoader,\
org.springframework.boot.env.YamlPropertySourceLoader
```

Where `PropertiesPropertySourceLoader` loads `.properties` and `.xml` files, and `YamlPropertySourceLoader` loads `.yml` and `.yaml`.

These are loaded with the [SpringFactoriesLoader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.22/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/SpringFactoriesLoader.html), which we can see in action in `org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener` (deprecated) or `org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver` (via `ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor` -> `ConfigDataEnvironment` -> `ConfigDataLocationResolvers`) :

```java
this.propertySourceLoaders = SpringFactoriesLoader.loadFactories(PropertySourceLoader.class,
                getClass().getClassLoader());
```

You can read in the [ConfigFileApplicationListener JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.3/api/org/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener.html) that the properties are indeed loaded with this class:

> EnvironmentPostProcessor that configures the context environment by loading properties from well known file locations. By default properties will be loaded from 'application.properties' and/or 'application.yml' files in the following locations:
> file:./config/
> file:./config/*/
> file:./
> classpath:config/
> classpath:
> ...

If you're interested in context loading from the environment in spring(boot), I suggest you setup your project with maven, download the sources jars, and have a look around in the mentioned `factories` file. You will find more relevant code in the `org.springframework.boot.env` and `org.springframework.boot.context` (`config` and `properties`) packages.

Answer (score -3):

You can find your application.yml or application.properties at the src/main/resources. You can have as many as possible configurations for your spring boot application for every case. Lets assume that you have 3 local-profiles like demo, production and server, so you made 3 configuration and assumingyou set for active profile the demo at the application.yml . I hope you get the idea. Its the first thing that actually is running before the springboot is up.

[Please look the officials docs !](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html)

Comment: The question is which class of the source code of spring the application.yml is handled.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.22.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html